# How to Duplicate multiple rows (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm trying to make a Procedure that will duplicate multiple rows of a table (or only one single row) and incrementing the ID for each row insertion.

My problem is that inside my procedure I used a cursor to select the rows to duplicate, when i select all rows without WHERE condition in that cursor everything works fine.
But when i set a WHERE condition to select only one row... nothing happens

Here is my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DuplicateEmployee (p_EmployeeID IN Employee.id%TYPE)
 AS
  p_New_EmployeeID Employee.id%TYPE;
  CURSOR c_DuplicateEmployee IS
    SELECT *
        FROM Employee
        WHERE Employee.id = p_EmployeeID; -- if this line is deleted all content is duplicated
  row_Employee c_DuplicateEmployee%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
      FOR myEmployee IN c_DuplicateEmployee LOOP
          p_New_EmployeeID := employee_seq.NEXTVAL;
          INSERT INTO Employee(id, first_name, last_name, start_date, end_date, salary, city, description)
            VALUES(p_New_EmployeeID, myEmployee.first_name, myEmployee.last_name, myEmployee.start_date, myEmployee.end_date, myEmployee.salary, myEmployee.city, myEmployee.description);
      END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
   END DuplicateEmployee;
```

I know in this example having a procedure selecting a primary key to duplicate is pointless but in my production base it will be used to select a Foreign key.

Bellow is the code require to create a the test table and SEQUENCE I used for this procedure

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
  (
    ID         VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    First_Name VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    Last_Name  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    Start_Date DATE,
    End_Date DATE,
    Salary      NUMBER(8,2),
    City        VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    Description VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
  );
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
  VALUES
    ('01', 'Jason', 'Martin', to_date('19960725','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20060725','YYYYMMDD'), 1234.56, 'Toronto', 'Programmer');
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
  VALUES
    ('02', 'Alison', 'Mathews', to_date('19760321','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('19860221','YYYYMMDD'), 6661.78, 'Vancouver', 'Tester');
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
  VALUES
    ('03', 'James', 'Smith', to_date('19781212','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('19900315','YYYYMMDD'), 6544.78, 'Vancouver', 'Tester');
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
  VALUES
    ('04', 'Celia', 'Rice', to_date('19821024','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('19990421','YYYYMMDD'), 2344.78, 'Vancouver', 'Manager');
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
  VALUES
    ('05', 'Robert', 'Black', to_date('19840115','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('19980808','YYYYMMDD'), 2334.78, 'Vancouver', 'Tester');
 INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
  VALUES
    ('06', 'Linda', 'Green', to_date('19870730','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('19960104','YYYYMMDD'), 4322.78, 'New York', 'Tester');
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
VALUES
    ('07', 'David', 'Larry', to_date('19901231','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('19980212','YYYYMMDD'), 7897.78, 'New York', 'Manager');
INSERT
INTO Employee
    (ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Start_Date, End_Date, Salary, City, Description)
VALUES
    ('08', 'James', 'Cat', to_date('19960917','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20020415','YYYYMMDD'), 1232.78, 'Vancouver', 'Tester');
```

Here for the Sequence that will manage Primary key (ID)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "TEST"."EMPLOYEE_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE ORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

And here the code to execute the procedure

```
BEGIN
  employeepackage.duplicateemployee(5);
END;
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't properly work for a single row when it's working to plicate all rows ? It there a limitation for cursors having less than 2 rows ?

Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need a cursor? You can do this with SQL directly:

```
INSERT INTO Employee(id, first_name, last_name, 
                     start_date, end_date, 
                     salary, city, description)
SELECT employee_seq.NEXTVAL, e.first_name, e.last_name,
       e.start_date, e.end_date, 
       e.salary, e.city, e.description
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.id = p_EmployeeID;
```

Anyway, the actual problem is that your `ID` is a `VARCHAR2(4)`, whereas you think it is a `NUMBER`. You actually do not have an employee with `ID = 5`, but you do have one with `ID = '05'`. So without changing anything, your procedure already works:

```
BEGIN
  employeepackage.duplicateemployee('05');
END;
```

Of course, it would make sense to change the data type of `ID`.

Comment: Thanks for such fast answer I didnt knew I could directly use a sequence.NEXVAL  directly in an INSERT statement !

Comment: @kwenji: Check also the [documentation on the INSERT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm). You can write arbitrary subqueries using the `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` syntax...

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I finally rememebred why I used cursor, because this example is only a part of a package that will duplicate rows of multiple tables and to duplicate childrens of an element I need to provide parent id.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from Lukas if fine for my first and last table that will not need to call others PROCEDURE to duplicate multiple children, though for intermediate table I used :

```
PROCEDURE Duplicate_Company (p_IdCity IN City.IdCity%TYPE) AS
p_New_IdCompany Company.IdCompany%TYPE;
CURSOR c_DuplicateCompany IS
SELECT *
    FROM Company c
    WHERE c.IdCity = p_IdCity; 
row_Company c_DuplicateCompany%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN c_DuplicateCompany LOOP
      p_New_IdCompany := company_seq.NEXTVAL;
      INSERT INTO Company(IdCompany, IdCity, Name, CreationDate)
        VALUES(p_New_IdCompany, c1.IdCity, c1.Name, c1.CreationDate);
      -- Call the procedure to duplicate current employee
      Duplicate_Employee(c1.IdCompany);
  END LOOP;
END Duplicate_Company;
```

Is it a good approach ?